# Calculate percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create table (columns) using another table(s), having trouble in the getting the desired columns. Please guide.

Table Names: Transactions, Customer, Prod_cat_info

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.cust_id, 
                c.gender, 
                C.city_code, 
                Datediff(mm, c.dob, Getdate())             AS AGE_IN_MONTHS, 
                (SELECT Count(transaction_id) 
                 FROM   transactions 
                 GROUP  BY tran_date)                      AS 
                basket_count_per_day, 
                (SELECT Sum(total_amt) 
                 FROM   transactions)                      AS Tot_sal_amt, 
                (SELECT Sum(qty) 
                 FROM   transactions)                      AS tot_sal_qnty, 
                (SELECT Count(DISTINCT prod_cat) 
                 FROM   dbo.prod_cat_info)                 AS Unq_cat_cnt, 
                (SELECT DISTINCT prod_subcat 
                 FROM   dbo.prod_cat_info)                 AS Unq_Scat_cnt, 
                (SELECT DISTINCT store_type 
                 FROM   dbo.transactions)                  AS Unq_chnl_cnt, 
                (SELECT Max(tran_date) 
                 FROM   dbo.transactions)                  AS 
                Last_Transaction_date, 
                (SELECT Avg(qty) / Count(tran_date) 
                 from transactions)                        AS 
                                                           Avg_basket_qty, 
                (SELECT Avg(total_amt) / Count(tran_date) 
                 from transactions)                                          
                                                         AS Avg_basket_val 
INTO   customer_360 
FROM   dbo.customer AS c 
       INNER JOIN dbo.transactions AS t 
               ON t.cust_id = c.customer_id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.prod_cat_info AS pci 
               ON pci.prod_cat_code = t.prod_cat_code
```

Error Message:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'dbo.Transactions.cust_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

[image: My Code]

Comment: Suggest you remove columns until it starts working again, to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The last two columns are aggregation queries. Because you have a SELECT with no FROM it will query the tables specified in the outer query.

```
            (SELECT Avg(qty) / Count(tran_date))       AS Avg_basket_qty, 
            (SELECT Avg(total_amt) / Count(tran_date)) AS Avg_basket_val
```

In this case you're aggregating qty,tran_date and total_amount, as such every other column needs either grouping or aggregating.

Adding the following should make it a valid query, it may not do what you want though!

```
GROUP BY T.cust_id, c.Gender, C.city_code, DATEDIFF(mm,c.DOB,GETDATE())
```

Comment: 1. unable to make t.cust_id as primary key using the below query(alter table Customer_360
add primary key (Customer_ID)

Comment: That's a different problem entirely! please make a new question

Comment: for the above same code, i'm able to create new table if i make the lines as comments where it has count(transaction_id), avg(qty), avg(total_amt). even though I'm using distinct, it is not allowing the customer_id as primary key

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY produces rows that are UNIQUE for the combination of values held in the columns you specify under that clause. Your overall query should look more like this, where the "non-aggregating columns" are listed in the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT
      T.cust_id    --<< this is a "non-aggregating" column
    , c.gender     --<< this is a "non-aggregating" column
    , C.city_code  --<< this is a "non-aggregating" column
    , DATEDIFF(mm, c.dob, GETDATE())    AS AGE_IN_MONTHS --<< this is a "non-aggregating" column

    , SUM(total_amt)                    AS Tot_sal_amt
    , SUM(qty)                          AS tot_sal_qnty
    , COUNT(DISTINCT store_type)        AS Unq_chnl_cnt
    , MAX(tran_date)                    AS Last_Transaction_date
    , AVG(qty) / COUNT(tran_date)       AS Avg_basket_qty
    , AVG(total_amt) / COUNT(tran_date) AS Avg_basket_val 

--INTO customer_360
FROM dbo.customer AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.transactions AS t ON t.cust_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY
      T.cust_id      --<< list each non-aggregating column here
    , c.gender       --<< list each non-aggregating column here
    , C.city_code    --<< list each non-aggregating column here
    , DATEDIFF(mm, c.dob, GETDATE())  --<< list each non-aggregating column here
```

- Note please that "select distinct" is **utterly, totally, completely redundant** if you are using GROUP BY (correctly) in the same select query. Also "select distinct" does less than GROUP BY can do for you (e.g. SUM/MIN/MAX/AVG values).

**Further notes:**

`AVG(qty) / COUNT(tran_date)` will produce an integer result, yo may want to do this instead **AVG(qty) / (COUNT(tran_date)*1.0)**

This join was removed `INNER JOIN dbo.prod_cat_info AS pci ON pci.prod_cat_code = t.prod_cat_code` as it is MIGHT multiply results. Compare the query above to another where this join is included. If the aggregations are affected then you will need a subquery against this table and join that instead. Due to this the following columns are missing too:

```
            (SELECT Count(DISTINCT prod_cat) 
             FROM   dbo.prod_cat_info)                 AS Unq_cat_cnt, 
            (SELECT DISTINCT prod_subcat 
             FROM   dbo.prod_cat_info)                 AS Unq_Scat_cnt,
```

These was also been removed as I wasn't certain what you intended with it:

```
            (SELECT Count(transaction_id) 
             FROM   transactions 
             GROUP  BY tran_date)  AS  basket_count_per_day,
```

A subquery such as this isn't permitted to return multiple values; which this will do. So it would cause an error and you need to decide how to incorporate "daily averages" into a table with one row per customer.

Comment: with this: (SELECT Count(transaction_id) 
             FROM   transactions 
             GROUP  BY tran_date)  AS  basket_count_per_day,
my intention was to get total transactions in a day

Comment: Yes I  can see that, but that isn't compatible with the balance of the query. It will not suit a single table structure, you need something else.

Comment: i have run the query you provided, it worked for whatever columns asked for. not sure about other reqd columns. will try again and ask your help if needed.Many thanks